# Compositing Nodes- doesn't render other layer?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
Okay honestly Im scared of making compositing noes because everytime I try to put more than 2 separate render layers either the first layer or the other layer gets shown in the render image, not those together.OMG! I want to be better at 3D and Im so depressed because of this problem. But I believe the future of me would be laughing at this.HElP!

Comment: could you upload  the blend file

Comment: hey Im from the future which is today. I learned everything so far and Im quite good at making them.